# find listing pruned folder when searching using -newer argument

Tags: find, cygwin

```
$ tree -D
.
├── [Jun 25 18:46]  dir1
│   └── [Jun 25 18:51]  file1
└── [Jun 25 17:59]  dir2
    └── [Jun 25 18:46]  file2

2 directories, 2 files

$ ls -l /tmp/since
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx None 0 Jun 25 18:45 /tmp/since
```

It is not clear, why the dir1 folder which is correctly getting excluded

```
$ find . -name dir1 -prune -o -type f -print
./dir2/file2
```

in above command, shows up in following command

```
$ find . -name dir1 -prune -o -type f -newer /tmp/since
./dir1
./dir2/file2
```

How can I rewrite above find command to list only files that changed
since timestamp of file /tmp/since, without visiting folder 'dir1'?

Comment: You can add `-print` at the end of your second `find` command.

Comment: Adding -print to second find command does help in producing expected output. Not clear why absence of that -print clause, pulls in ./dir1 as a match, when the -prune clause should have excluded that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do :

```
$ find . -name dir1 -prune -o -type f -newer /tmp/since
```

`find` adds implicitly a `-print` to make it become

```
$ find . \( -name dir1 -prune -o -type f -newer /tmp/since \) -print
```

As `-name dir1 -prune` is true for `dir1`, `-print` is executed, even though the children of `dir1` are not processed.

When you add `-print` explicitly, it is interpreted as :

```
$ find . \( -name dir1 -prune \) -o \( -type f -newer /tmp/since -print \)
```

so when `-name dir1 -prune` is true, the rest is bypassed, hence `dir1` is not printed.